# Doesn't allocate memory to IVRs while adding VC as UINav rootVC

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management

**EDITED**

This is a very common problem I am facing during coding, please take a look at it.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
// Override point for customization after application launch.

// Adding Landing screen landscape on mainwindow
self.landingViewController = [[LandingViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"LandingViewController" bundle:nil];
[self.window addSubview:self.landingViewController.view];
self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
```

}

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class RecentPlanViewController;
@class ChevronViewController;


@interface LandingViewController : UIViewController
{
 UINavigationController *navigationController;

    // custom view controllers
RecentPlanViewController *recentPlanViewController;
ChevronViewController *chevronViewController;

}

- (void)popView:(NSNotification *)notification;


@property (nonatomic,retain) UINavigationController *navigationController;
@property (nonatomic,retain) RecentPlanViewController *recentPlanViewController;
@property (nonatomic,retain) ChevronViewController *chevronViewController;
@end


self.recentPlanViewController = [[RecentPlanViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"RecentPlanViewController" bundle:nil];

[self.recentPlanViewController loadView];   // if I skip this : Memory to recentPlanViewController's IVs not allocated.

self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.recentPlanViewController ];


#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class RecentPlanCell;


@interface RecentPlanViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
IBOutlet UITableView *recentPlanTableView; // Main recent TableView
RecentPlanCell *recentPlanCell;
IBOutlet UIButton *createPlanButton;
IBOutlet UIButton *viewAllPlanButton;
BOOL isViewingAllPlans;   // Yes if view all plan pressed
}

@property (nonatomic,retain) RecentPlanCell *recentPlanCell;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *createPlanButton;
@property (nonatomic,retain) IBOutlet UIButton *viewAllPlanButton;

@end
```

There are two conclusions to above written code.

1.If I use loadView method. It calls out the view controller's view and allocate memory just to IBOutlets and doesn't do for other `self.recentPlanViewController` Instance variables.

2.If I skip second line of code, it doesn't allocate memory to any IVR even after using it as rootVC.

Please guide me, what is the memory management concept I'm violating!

Thanks

Comment: You should edit your code again, because there are some lines of code between the interface definition and implementation, and it's not clear what the blocks of code are.

Also, can you make clear what your problem is? Because it seems that's diverged from the original question.

Comment: it didn't sort out yet!!

Comment: @turtle Your notion of an iVar in objective-C (in regards to memory management is flawed).  There is no OOP Lang on earth that auto-allocs memory for variables without explicitly being asked to.  Objective-C especially, but the compiler is exceptionally nice to you, so your iVars are initialized to `nil`, unlike C where you would have gotten a garbage value.

Comment: @CodaFi Then how to tag an action to particular iVar. As I know if a `ViewContoller` class has been allocated some memory, allocates memory space to it's iVars too. Isn't it?
I also used that particular `ViewController` while pushing onto a `NavigationController`.

Answer (score 2):

There are a few problems:

- you're calling `loadView` directly
- you're not showing the view controller's view

## `loadView`

The [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html) says:

> If you cannot define your views in a storyboard or a nib file, override the loadView method to manually instantiate a view hierarchy and assign it to the view property.

And:

> You should never call this method directly [loadView]. The view controller calls this method when its view property is requested but is currently nil. This method loads or creates a view and assigns it to the view property.

### What does this mean?

There are three ways to provide a view for a view controller:

- using storyboards
- using nibs
- programmatically

So, since you are talking about `IBOutlet`s, the third way has to be excluded.

### When are `IBOutlet`s 'ready'?

Enter `viewDidLoad`:

> This method is called after the view controller has loaded its view hierarchy into memory. This method is called regardless of whether the view hierarchy was loaded from a nib file or created programmatically in the loadView method.

After this method has been called, your `IBOutlet`s are ready, and you can safely access them.

## Showing views

I don't know what your hierarchy of view controller is, but you're probably reassigning the `navigationController` instead of reusing it.

If that view controller is pushed from another view controller you should do this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:self.recentPlanViewController animated:YES];
```

in order to reuse the `navigationController` that's managing the hierarchy (and not reassigning it).

So, the question is: how are you showing the `LandingViewController`?

Answer (score 1):

The thing is, `loadView` is called automatically, you should not call it yourself. For it to be called your `UIViewController` must appear on the screen. What you have at the moment is a pointer to your `recentPlanViewController` and that's it. In order for `loadView`, `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear` to be called you need to something like:

```
[self pushViewController:self.recentPlanViewController];
```

You should not rely on your `IBOutlets` until the `UIViewController` is actually on the screen. If you want to have your `IBOutlets` have some default values on the beginning, you should pass them on the `init` method, save them as ivars, and then set them in `viewDidLoad`, for example.

**Edit:**

There might be a problem with this:

```
self.navigationController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.recentPlanViewController ];
```

Because you are re-initialising your own navigationController.

**Edit 2:**

If you just want to show your new `UIViewController` assuming that you already have a working `UINavigationController`, you can do:

```
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:self.recentPlanViewController animated:YES];
```

If you don't have a `self.navigationController` you can do:

```
[self presentViewController:self.recentPlanViewController animated:YES completion:^{

}];
```

Comment: No, because the IBOutlets are not loaded yet. But don't trust me... Do the following `NSLog(@"My IBoutlet %@",aOutlet);` and see what comes out of it on the `initWithRootViewController `

Comment: Jacky, I am able to post my VC on to NavigationController but the problem is:
Instance variable possessed by VC didn't get memory allocated. So that I can perform some action on that. 
I accept that there is no need of calling `loadView` explicitly, but  on pushing VC or adding as root..is not working for me!!

Comment: Check my edit. And tell me what you want to do with your `recentPlanViewController`

Comment: I also edited my code. After pushing `recentPlanViewController` I want to perform some actions on my IBOutlets like on `createPlanButton` or `recentPlanTableView`. 
Normal scenario is: 
All `recentPlanViewController` IVRs should get some memory after initializing `recentPlanViewController` and using it on NavigationController. But it's not happening!
Did you get me?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18390/discussion-between-turtle-and-jacky-boy)

Answer (score 0):

**the work around is:**
associate or use the iVars in the view controller itself.